# Find a specific element of a matrix in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a nested matrix in Python. I want to find the index of an element that contains a specific number among the elements of the matrix. For example, in the list below I want to show an element from my list that 205 is the third number of that element. I want to do the job without using a special function. Thank you for helping me to do this.
`My_List = [[254, 47, 845, 698], [12, 5, 7, 36], [2, 5, 9, 7], [110, 45, 205, 7], [86, 93, 14, 16], [18, 95, 63, 1]]`

Comment: what you tried to achieve this? can you please help us with some efforts of what you tried ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. I'm new to Python.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"I have no idea" is off-topic for Stack Overflow;
this site is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Working through those is your job before you post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a special function:

```
MyList = ...

def find_index(lst, val):
    for i,row in enumerate(lst):
        if row[2] == val:
            return i

index = find_index(MyList, 205)
```